# Start navigation once user selects carousel item

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have a list of items which are returned by my api. The cards display fine and I pass in the address as the key in optionInfo object.

I see that when I click one of these items, the address is returned. How do I use this address to start maps for navigation?

TIA

Comment: To be clear, are you looking to launch a different application on a mobile device when they select the destination? Are you looking to do this specifically for Android, or for iOS as well?

Comment: Looking to start google maps using the maps api., something like https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=pizza+seattle+wa.

Comment: Need to fo this on both iOS and Android from the google assistant app.

Comment: Hmm. Are you calling the addButton() member function on the basic card and passing the full URL (http://google.com/maps...) as its second parameter?